# fancybox does works only on last image in chrome and FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, gallery, fancybox

In firefox Fancybox only works on the last image (last image in the source, not the visual webpage).
In IE everything works fine.

I changed ID into CLASS, but no succes yet.
You can find the source here:
http://www.luukratief-design.nl/dump/parallax/stack.html

please help! Bugging me for hours now.

Answer (score 1):

The anchors are being positioned up top.

To see what I mean, open Firebug's console and type this

```
$('a.big').css({ border: '6px solid red' })
```

Now look at the red boxes all bunched up top.

I think this is because the effect is being added to the images, and not the parent links. The images are being displayed using `position: absolute`, and because the anchors don't have `position: relative`, the anchors are collapsing like they have no content.

Since you are using JavaScript, could you do something like this?

```
$('a.big').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation(); // in case it bubbles up the parent anchor somehow and fires twice in IE
    // trigger lightbox here..
    $(this).parent('a').click();
});
```

Not sure if this will work, but it might be on the right track... good luck.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Since i am a javascript/jquery noob, can you please tell me where to put this snippet?

I now added it in the script in the head, but does not seem to work.
I seen what you mean by turning the borders on.

Comment: I can see you have added it, and in the right place. Is there any change? You might also want to add `css({ cursor: 'hand' })` to help users know you can click the images.

Comment: I'd go first with testing the events. Throw a `console.log('g\'day mate')` or similar. Test in IE using `alert()` if you want, or use a proper JavaScript debugger.

Comment: wow, this is all to much for me to understand.
It should not have a cursor hand since it's a href.
The last image works in FF and Chrome, the others dont.

The fix you gave me did not work. thanks for trying though